# Is Session Port Specific?

Tags: node.js, session

I am writing two application on localhost and don't want them to share certain information (Likely on session).

I am wondering if I can open two port? Is the Session storage port specific?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am wondering if I can open two port?

Yes, you listen on two ports, by starting two servers, one for each port.

> Is the Session storage port specific?

Yes and no.  It depends upon how the session is configured.

Cookies are not port-specific so by itself a session cookie would be shared between two servers on the same host, but different ports.

So, if you want two instances of express-session on two separate web servers on the same host, but separate ports to use separate sessions, then you can initialize express-session to use separate cookies for each session (by specifying a different cookie name for each) and initialize two separate instances of express-session and then the two sessions will be completely separate.

Here's an example:

```
const express = require('express');
const session = require('express-session');

// configure first server and session middleware
const app1 = express();
app1.use(session({
  secret: 'keyboard cat',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie: { secure: true },
  name: 'session1'
}));
app1.listen(8080);

// configure second server and separate session middleware/session cookie
const app2 = express();
app2.use(session({
  secret: 'keyboard cat',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie: { secure: true },
  name: 'session2'
}));
app2.listen(8081);
```

And, if you're specifying a specific storage medium for the session, then you need to make sure you initialize those to be separate storage locations.

Comment: I do not understand how you have specified cookies for ports. I have two separate applications with different ports on localhost and their cookies interfere with each other. One runs on `node.js`. The other is on `C++`.

Comment: @ar2015 - As my answer says, cookies are not port specific so two servers using the same DNS name and different ports will share cookies.  What I did in my answer is use two separate cookie names for each of the sessions so they sessions themselves would not interfere with each other.  So, if you're going to share cookies, you just have to make sure that none of the cookie names clash.  You could use a different DNS name (each points to the same IP address) for each server and that would give you separate cookies for each.